# AppleScript email with rich content on OSX 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: email, applescript, html-email, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to send styled text email through AppleScript via default mail client. It seems new version of OSX is not able to recognise the HTML content set inside. Is there any workaround for 10.11 (El Capitan)?

Solution is working pretty much fine with 10.10 (Yosemite).

```
tell application "Mail"
    set theMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:textSubject, visible:false}
    tell theMessage
        set html content to textBody
        repeat with i from 1 to count toNameList
            make new to recipient at theMessage with properties {name:item i of toNameList, address:item i of toAddressList}
        end repeat
        send
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. I noticed that using 'html content' I get an email with the subject but the body is empty. There is no content. If I change it to 'content' I get all of my content, but obviously just not processed as html, so all the tags are also visible. I am suspecting that Mail changed it's applescript interface in El Capitan.

Comment: Looking through the applescript dictionary for Mail, I no longer see html content as a property of both message and outgoing message. I wonder if they got rid of it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to say that the **html content** property of the Mail.app is **deprecated** by Apple. To verify this, it is enough to view the dictionary file **/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/Recours/Mail.sdef** with TextEdit.app. This is the place:

```
    <property name="html content" code="htda" type="text" access="w" hidden="yes"
 description="Does nothing at all (deprecated)"/>
```

But, that doesn't mean you can't create a message with **well-written HTML**.

Personally, I prefer not to mess with the correct HTML writing, and edit the body of the message in TextEdit.app, save it as an RTF file, and run the following script.

```
-- script: Create Mail message with rich content
-- written: by @KniazidisR, posted on stackoverflow.com 22 April 2023

use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions
-- classes, constants, and enums used
property NSUTF8StringEncoding : a reference to 4
property NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail : a reference to current application's NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail
property NSAttributedString : a reference to current application's NSAttributedString
property NSString : a reference to current application's NSString
property NSSharingService : a reference to current application's NSSharingService

set rtfFile to choose file with prompt "Choose the RTF file to email as HTML:" without invisibles
set theHTML to do shell script "/usr/bin/textutil -stdout -format rtf -convert html " & quoted form of POSIX path of rtfFile

set messageSubject to "My converted rtf to html"
set recipientAddresses to {"kniazidis.rompert@gmail.com"}

set theSource to NSString's stringWithString:theHTML
set theData to theSource's dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
set anAttributedString to NSAttributedString's alloc()'s initWithHTML:theData documentAttributes:{}

-- USE THE MAIL SHARING SERVICE TO CREATE A NEW MAIL MESSAGE
set aSharingService to NSSharingService's sharingServiceNamed:(NSSharingServiceNameComposeEmail)
if aSharingService's canPerformWithItems:recipientAddresses then
    set aSharingService's subject to messageSubject
    set aSharingService's recipients to recipientAddresses
    tell aSharingService to performSelectorOnMainThread:"performWithItems:" withObject:{anAttributedString} waitUntilDone:false
end if
```

**Note**: Of course, if you have well-written HTML at your disposal, there is no need to create an RTF. Just write directly this HTML to **theHTML** script variable.